# Run Laravel Database Migration after every build on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel-5

I am running Laravel 5.5 on GAE with a MySQL instance running database. I want to be able to run database migrations after every build. I have added command "php artisan migrate" on post-install-cmd in composer.json but it does not seem to work.

```
"post-install-cmd": [
        "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
        "php artisan migrate",
        "php artisan cache:clear"
    ]
```

The build log shows command running but looks like down there there is command cancelled. What could be the issue? How can I run migration after every build? Any help will be appreciated.

[Here is screenshot of the build logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZkKw.png)

SQL error:

```
ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = My_DB_NAME and table_name = migrations) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = My_DB_NAME and table_name = migrations) at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connec‌​tion.php:664, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at
```

Comment: App Engine logs are in the [Logging tab](console.cloud.google.com/logs) filtering by GAE Application. However, if you Google the error ( `laravel migrate SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` ), you may find some answers that can also help you. Finally, [here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible) there is a guide for running Laravel on AppEngine that you may want to have a look at. One last question: have you tried running the migration command in the CloudSQL instance and not from the AppEngine deployment? Does that work?

Comment: The tutorial you have provided is what I followed. The app deploys and runs well, I can connect to the database but migrations are not running. For the part of running migration command in the CloudSQL instance how can I do that?

Comment: The logs dont show anything unsusual. Again the error is when I am deploying (Its a build error) not application error. After deploying the application works fine, connects with the SQL instance (database), inserts and retrieves data. NB: I created some dummy table and data using the cloud console

Comment: You can also see logs about versions creation and updates, if you filter by `activity` in the second dropdown menu in the Log filters (or with the filter `logName="projects/<PROJECT_ID>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"
`). You can perform the migratino locally following Step 6 in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-flexible#set-up-database-sessions) you said you were following.

Comment: I want to run the migrations in production not locally. For locally they are running well.

Comment: Does your application work running it without the `php artisan migrate` command in the `post-install-cmd`? Try that and see if the same error comes up.

Comment: Yes it works fine

Comment: I have been able to reproduce your issue. I have not been able to solve it, though. However, there are a couple of things I noticed during my reproduction, which you may have a look while an answer to your issue is found: check that the `database.php` file has an entry under `mysql` like `            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/cloudsql/<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>')`. Make sure that you are using `        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*"` at least. Check the logs when running `gcloud app deploy` to confirm that the specified version of laravel is being installed.

Comment: The version of Laravel being installed is 5.5.28 .Even after adding 'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/cloudsql/<SQL_INSTANCE_NAME>') I still get the same error.

Comment: @BenjaminMwendwaMunyoki have you managed to solve it? ran into the same issue..

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

You need to set up cloud SQL connection to production DB and your laravel app at your build server. Then you run migrations after the code is deployed to google.

---

*How to install gcloud SDK?*

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-bitbucket (check bitbucket-pipelines.yml)

*How to setup google cloud SQL proxy?*

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

*How to setup laravel app to connect to cloud SQL proxy?*

Add `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` & `DB_PORT=3306` to `.env` file, or whatever port you choose.

Run migration and enjoy!

---

**Long answer:**

When you SSH into GAE instance, you can't see your code just yet. It's hidden beneath another layer of Docker containers. In my case, there are 5 containers running: gaeapp, cloudsql, api, nginx_proxy and fluentd_logger. As you can see, cloudsql is one of the containers, which means that both your app container and cloudsql has to be built in order to connect to each other.

What most likely happens is that container with your code is provisioned before cloundsql one. As an effect, any database related command, or if you have database related code executed during the laravel startup, results in SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory because /cloudsql/ directory/socket is not ready yet.

Therefore the most straightforward way is to run migrations from anywhere else but not from GAE. It might be also possible to update docker config of GAE, but I'm not that familiar with it.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `--no-interaction` and `--force` flags to the migrate command. Since you're in production, it is prompting for `Y` or `N` to run the command.

```
php artisan migrate  --no-interaction --force
```

Comment: When I do that, I get this error  ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = My_DB_NAME and table_name = migrations)  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = My_DB_NAME and table_name = migrations) at /app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at

Comment: Well something isn't where it's supposed to be. Can you verify that the migration files are in `database/migrations`? Also, does `My_DB_NAME` need to be replaced, or is that the actual name of your database?

Comment: I replace the database name with My_DB_NAME on this comment for security reasons

Comment: Check your logs files in `storage/logs`, does it contain a full stack trace for this exception? It will be helpful to know which file doesn't exist.

Comment: My two cents thinking is before Laravel runs runs migrations, the app is trying to access the migration table to see which batch of migrations have not been run. Since the table is not created (migrations also create migration table), it returns the error since it can't find the table

Comment: It is in your application root directory. For example, `/var/www/myApp/storage/logs/`

Comment: Question, does the database exist? Can you verify it has been created before this runs?

Comment: There is no such directory. I am using Google App Engine deploy I think it builds an image of the app

Comment: The database exists. I created one table manually with some dummy data and the application can connect to and access/display the data

Comment: I guess try adding this to the command also `--env=production`. So `php artisan migrate  --no-interaction --force --env=production`. It seems it's having trouble establishing the socket connection.

Comment: Getting this error: Script php artisan migrate --no-interaction --force --env=production handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c /build-scripts/composer.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1

Comment: Sounds like you may not have your environment properly set up. Do you have a local development machine you can run that command on to see if it gives the same results?

Comment: Local environment runs well and creates users table and password_resets_table

Comment: I would need to see log files or complete stack traces at this point to determine what is happening. Something tells me the MySQL socket is getting created/is not accessible in your production environment.

Comment: Where can I get the log files in production environment?

Comment: From Google App Engine, unfortunately I'm not familiar with that technology so I can't help you out on how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Was not able to add such a long log file as a comment. So trying here.

<pre>
[2020-05-03 08:51:50] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = aimforthesky and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = aimforthesky and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') at /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(631): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#1 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(339): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#2 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php(18): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from i...', Array)
#3 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(169): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\MySqlBuilder->hasTable('migrations')
#4 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(608): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()
#5 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(93): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->repositoryExists()
#6 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(64): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase()
#7 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(541): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\{closure}()
#8 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(81): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->usingConnection(NULL, Object(Closure))
#9 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
#10 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(33): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(36): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#12 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(91): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#13 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#14 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(592): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#15 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#16 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#17 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#18 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(912): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#19 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#20 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#21 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#22 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#23 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#24 {main}
[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory at /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('mysql:unix_sock...', 'root', '', Array)
#1 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:unix_sock...', 'root', '', Array)
#2 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:unix_sock...', Array, Array)
#3 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(182): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#5 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(926): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#6 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(961): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#7 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(405): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getReadPdo()
#8 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(331): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdoForSelect(true)
#9 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(664): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from i...', Array)
#10 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(631): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#11 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(339): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from i...', Array, Object(Closure))
#12 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/MySqlBuilder.php(18): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from i...', Array)
#13 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/DatabaseMigrationRepository.php(169): Illuminate\\Database\\Schema\\MySqlBuilder->hasTable('migrations')
#14 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(608): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\DatabaseMigrationRepository->repositoryExists()
#15 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(93): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->repositoryExists()
#16 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(64): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->prepareDatabase()
#17 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php(541): Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\{closure}()
#18 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php(81): Illuminate\\Database\\Migrations\\Migrator->usingConnection(NULL, Object(Closure))
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand->handle()
#20 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(33): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(36): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#22 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(91): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#23 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(35): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#24 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(592): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#25 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(134): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#26 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))
#27 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(121): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\\Console\\OutputStyle))#28 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(912): Illuminate\\Console\\Command->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(264): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Console\\Migrations\\MigrateCommand), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(140): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(93): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#32 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->run(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#33 /home/nitish/code/aimforthesky/artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#34 {main}
"}
</pre>
```